# What does the term POI mean in the context of graduate admissions?

Tags: graduate-admissions, terminology

I hear the term POI used in graduate admissions. What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POI stands for Professor of Interest -- i.e., the faculty member that is most likely to take the most interest in your application portfolio and is likely to be your advisor if you were to gain admission.